# Non moveable std::array

Tags: arrays, c++11, visual-studio-2013, move-semantics

I'm implementing tabu search algorithm in Visual Studio 2013.

I would like to have a function that generates neighbourhood
(it is an `std::array` of `std::unique_ptr`'s to the objects of class `Neighbour`).

Unfortunately, i can't move `std::array` of unique pointers (I can move `std::unique_ptr<Neighbour>`).

I've checked that `std::unique_ptr<Neighbour>` must be moveable - so it is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <array>


class Neighbour {
public:
   virtual ~Neighbour(){};
};


class Neighbourhood
{
public:
  using Neighbours = std::array<std::unique_ptr<Neighbour>, 12>;

protected:
  Neighbours neighbourhood;
  unsigned size;
};


int main()
{
  Neighbourhood::Neighbours n1;
  Neighbourhood::Neighbours n2;

  n2 = std::move(n1);
}
```

On Coliru it is working: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c52a6a7a148350a
I suppose that something is wrong with implementation of C++11 in Visual Studio 2013.

Do you know how can I fix it?

And the error is:

```
1>------Build started : Project : Project5, Configuration : Debug Win32------
  1>  Source.cpp
  1>c:\users\radek\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\project5\project5\source.cpp(29) : error C2280 : 'std::unique_ptr<Neighbour,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::operator =(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
  1>          with
  1>[
    1>              _Ty = Neighbour
      1>]
      1>          c:\program files(x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\memory(1487) : see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr<Neighbour,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::operator ='
      1>          with
      1>[
        1>              _Ty = Neighbour
          1>]
          1>          This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'std::array<std::unique_ptr<Neighbour,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,12> &std::array<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,12>::operator =(const std::array<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,12> &)'
          1>          with
          1>[
            1>              _Ty = Neighbour
              1>]
              == == == == == Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up - to - date, 0 skipped == == == == ==
```

Answer (score 1):

VS2013 does not automatically generate move constructors. Simply implement the move constructor for your class and it will compile and run as you expect.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work. The same error.